# Differences between Security group and access key

Tags: amazon-web-services

Just googling about the differences between security group and access key in aws. But unable to find the profound details. Could anyone explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Security groups are rules to allow traffic to instances. This can be considered similar to iptables in linux.

Access keys are credentials that you can use to manage AWS activity from command line or code.

Answer (score 1):

A security group is a set of rules for inbound and outbound communication. An access key is a credential for authenticating a user, just like a username + password combination is a set of credentials for authenticating a user.